# Can a store-release be reordered with a subsequent sequential-consistent load in C++11?

Tags: c++, c++11, memory-model, stdatomic

A store with `std::memory_order_release` to some location can be reordered with a subsequent load from another location with `std::memory_order_acquire`.

But can a store with `std::memory_order_release` to some location be reordered with a subsequent load from another location with `std::memory_order_seq_cst`?

Analogously, can a store with `std::memory_order_seq_cst` to a variable be reordered with a subsequent load from another location with `std::memory_order_acquire`?

Consider this example:

```
std::atomic<int> x{0};
std::atomic<int> y{0};

void thread1() {
    x.store(std::memory_order_release, 1);
    int r1 = y.load(std::memory_order_seq_cst);
    std::cout << r1 << std::endl;
}

void thread2() {
    y.store(std::memory_order_seq_cst, 1);
    int r2 = x.load(std::memory_order_acquire);
    std::cout << r2 << std::endl;
}
```

It is well known (http://bartoszmilewski.com/2008/11/05/who-ordered-memory-fences-on-an-x86/) that if both `std::memory_order_seq_cst` were replaced by their release/acquire counterpart the output could be two times "0".

Does the sequential-consistency buy anything in this example or can the output still be two times "0"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the sequential-consistency does not buy anything in this example and the output can still be two times "0".

The only difference between `std::memory_order_seq_cst` and `std::memory_order_acquire/release` is that `std::memory_order_seq_cst`-stores may not be reordered with subsequent `std::memory_order_seq_cst`-loads to *different* variables/locations, see Herb Sutter's "atomic<> Weapons" talk. (Of course, it may never happen that stores are reordered with subsequent loads to the same variable.)

But, as soon as only one (let alone both) of the memory-orders gets weakened (as is the case in both threads in the example) the StoreLoad reordering may happen. That means, in the example both loads may be reordered before their respective store.

This means that a program that only contains a single `std::memory_order_seq_cst` and otherwise only `std::memory_order_release/acquire` remains the same program if one were to replace the lonely `std::memory_order_seq_cst` by `std::memory_order_release` (if it is with a store) or a `std::memory_order_acquire` (if it is with a load).